# Not showing data when is authenticated (guards)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.3

For the first time I am using web guards to create other types of users, in my case are candidates and employers, it looks it works fine, but I notice one detail, I have a partial called `nav.blade.ph`p where I have the menu titles and listing of links of user account, if the user is logged in it should show links for the administration if not it shows the buttons for login or registration. The menu partial updates when I am logged in, but I notice it only works when the route is inside of a guard, I don't understand why doesn't work the partial navigation for example on the home page (out of the middleware).

Can some tell me what is missing?

Routes:

```
Route::get('/','PageController@getHome');

// CANDIDATE PRIVATE AREA
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:candidate']], function() {

    Route::prefix('candidate')->group(function(){
        Route::get('/panel','CandidateController@dashboard');

});
```

Partial nav.blade.php

```
 @if(Auth::check())
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{ Auth::User()->name }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                            @if(Auth::guard('employer')->check())
                                <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Dashboard</a></li>

                                <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> Settings</a></li>
                                <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Online Store</a></li>
                            @endif

                            @if(Auth::guard('candidate')->check())
                                <li><a href="{{route('candidate-dashboard')}}">Panel</a></li>
                            @endif

                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>

                                <li>  <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></span> Logout
                                </a></li>

                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                </form>
                            @else
                                <div class="navbar-form">
                                    <a class="btn btn-success " href="">Login</a>  | <a class="btn btn-success " href="">Register</a>
                                </div>


                            @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Route::get('/','PageController@getHome');

// CANDIDATE PRIVATE AREA
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest:candidate']], function() {

    Route::prefix('candidate')->group(function(){
        Route::get('/panel','CandidateController@dashboard');

});
```